# How can I extract Table data in XML format with specific format mention in description?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to create a XML document with some of the few data. but I am unable to created expected XML based on the StudentData table format.

***Database Table output***

TableName: StudentData

```
| KeyName    | KeyValue       |
|------------|----------------|
| StudentID  | 123456         |
| FirstName  | John           |
| LastName   | Doe            |
| Email      | jdoe@gmail.com |
| Phone      | 1234567890     |
```

I am trying to make an output based on below result

Below is expected results

```
<TestData>
  <Parameter key="StudentID">123456</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="FirstName">John</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="LastName">Doe</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="Email">jdoe@gmail.com</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="Phone">1234567890</Parameter>
</TestData>
```

If I have KeyName as FieldName then it would be easy to make XML Data as per `Select` statement shown below. Also I know that PIVOT can work in my above StudentData table format but that would be too lengthy process.

```
SELECT 'StudentID' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,StudentID AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,'FirstName' AS [Parameter/@key]
       , FirstName AS [Parameter]
       ,''
       ,'LastName' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,LastName AS [Parameter]
       ,'Email' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,Email AS [Parameter]
       ,'Phone' AS [Parameter/@key]
       ,Phone AS [Parameter]
FROM StudentData
FOR XML PATH('TestData');
```

**Question 1**: How can I make XML based on StudentData Table I have?

**Question 2**: How can I make it dynammic if incase new row(s) then XML is also added?

Hope you are understanding my question here. If you have any questions. Please add a comment.

**PN**: StudentData table format cannot be changed. So I have to work the current table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrasing is a little confusing, but if I understand you correctly, consider the following.

**Example**

```
Select [Parameter/@key]=KeyName
      ,[Parameter]     =KeyValue
 from YourTable for XML Path(''),Root('TestData')
```

**Returns**

```
<TestData>
  <Parameter key="StudentID">123456</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="FirstName">John</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="LastName">Doe</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="Email">jdoe@gmail.com</Parameter>
  <Parameter key="Phone">1234567890</Parameter>
</TestData>
```

Comment: @user1413 We all overthink it from time to time  :)